# How to print bytes in hexadecimal using System.out.println?

Tags: java, system, byte

I've declared a byte array (I'm using Java):

```
byte test[] = new byte[3];
test[0] = 0x0A;
test[1] = 0xFF;
test[2] = 0x01;
```

How could I print the different values stored in the array?

If I use System.out.println(test[0]) it will print '10'. I'd like it to print 0x0A

Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(test[0]));
```

OR *(pretty print)*

```
System.out.printf("0x%02X", test[0]);
```

OR *(pretty print)*

```
System.out.println(String.format("0x%02X", test[0]));
```

Comment: Of all of these, the `System.out.printf` is probably the best idea.

Comment: But the `Integer.toHexString` will print `10` not `0x0A`.

Answer (score 9):

```
for (int j=0; j<test.length; j++) {
   System.out.format("%02X ", test[j]);
}
System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
byte test[] = new byte[3];
test[0] = 0x0A;
test[1] = 0xFF;
test[2] = 0x01;

for (byte theByte : test)
{
  System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(theByte));
}
```

NOTE: test[1] = 0xFF; this wont compile, you cant put 255 (FF) into a byte, java will want to use an int.

you might be able to do...

```
test[1] = (byte) 0xFF;
```

I'd test if I was near my IDE (if I was near my IDE I wouln't be on Stackoverflow)

Comment: You can definitely do 
   byte b = 255 & 0xFF; 
And then when reading it 
   int calculation = (0xFF &b) + 5; 
to read back 255