# Getting the binary form of an image in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to get the binary form of an image in android to send to a server, but it's not working. When I printed the bytes being created it returns this : [B@cfc2978

```
public Byte[] getImageBytes(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPG, 50, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    System.out.println(imageBytes);                    
    return imageBytes;
}
```

Can Anyone help me find out why this is happening and how to fix it? To clarify, i need to send the binary form of the image to the server to be processed. The testing was done through the emulator.

Comment: Yes, you're seeing the result of calling `toString()` on a byte array, that's all. The actual bytes are being returned fine - you're just not printing that information.

Comment: What is not working? You only misused `toString()` on an array which does not affect the `return` at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print bytes in hexadecimal using System.out.println?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748021/how-to-print-bytes-in-hexadecimal-using-system-out-println)